# Javascript Form upload using Ajax

Tags: javascript

I use the following function to upload a form using ajax,

```
function directConvert(form, action_url, div_id){
        // Create the iframe...
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("name", "upload_iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("width", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("height", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("border", "0");
        iframe.setAttribute("style", "width: 0; height: 0; border: none;");  
        // Add to document...
        form.parentNode.appendChild(iframe);
        window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";   
        iframeId = document.getElementById("upload_iframe");     
        // Add event...
        var eventHandler = function () {     
                if (iframeId.detachEvent) iframeId.detachEvent("onload",eventHandler);
                else iframeId.removeEventListener("load", eventHandler, false);             
                // Message from server...            

                if (iframeId.contentDocument) {
                    content = iframeId.contentDocument.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.contentWindow) {
                    content = iframeId.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                } else if (iframeId.document) {
                    content = iframeId.document.body.innerHTML;
                }                   
                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = content;     
                // Del the iframe...
                setTimeout('iframeId.parentNode.removeChild(iframeId)',50);
            }    
        if (iframeId.addEventListener) iframeId.addEventListener("load", eventHandler, true);
        if (iframeId.attachEvent) iframeId.attachEvent("onload", eventHandler); 
        // Set properties of form...
        form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");
        form.setAttribute("action", action_url);
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        form.setAttribute("encoding", "multipart/form-data");  
        form.submit();      
    }
```

but after submitting,form opens in **New Window instead of opening in the same window**.How to fix the issue?

Comment: Do you observe this behaviour in all browsers?

Comment: _"I use the following function to upload a form using ajax"_ - You're _not_ using Ajax, you're doing a standard form submit from within the iframe. What happens if you remove this line: `form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe");` - without that the response should go to the iframe by default...

Comment: Why did you put `window.frames['upload_iframe'].name = "upload_iframe";` code into the script?

Comment: after removing form.setAttribute("target", "upload_iframe"); it has no effect.Is there any other way of doing it without using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using 
`iframe.setAttribute("target", "_parent");` or so?

Comment: I tries using iframe.setAttribute("target", "_parent"); but Form opens in other page.i need to display it in a div.Is there any other way of doing it without using iframes?